# Running multiple functions with one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

```
method1()
{
    while(1)
    {
         some task;
         sleep(900); //sleep for .9 second
    }
}
method2()
{
    some task;
}
AfxBeginThread(method1, NULL);
```

I want to call method2 every one minute inside method1 but while loop runs every ~1 second. Can I call method2 from method1 every 1 minute? If Yes How?, If No How can I call method2 every one minute without creating another thread?

Comment: Why do not you not want to create another thread to run `method2` every minute?

Comment: How precisely do you need to time it? If your loop runs approximately one iteration per second, then anything you do on every 60th iteration of the loop will happen approximately once every minute.

Comment: P.S., Don't say "trigger" if all you really mean is "call." Would it satisfy your requirement if the loop in `method1()` were to _call_ `method2()` once every minute?

Comment: @SolomonSlow . Yes, but how?

Comment: Also precision is very important, method2 should be called exactly 1440 times a day.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply have `method1` poll the system periodically to see if 1 minute has passed, eg:

```
method1()
{
    auto start = ...; // GetTickCount/64(), std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), etc

    while (not stopped)
    {
        some task;
        Sleep(900); //sleep for .9 second

        auto end = ...; // GetTickCount/64(), std::chrono::steady_clock::now(), etc
        if ((end-start) > 60000ms)
        {
            method2();
            start = end;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another way is to have `method1` use a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) instead, set to 1 minute intervals, and then the loop can call `method2` whenever the timer has elapsed, eg:

```
method1()
{
    HANDLE timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    LARGE_INTEGER DueTime;
    DueTime.QuadPart = -600000000; // due in 1 minute from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer, &DueTime, 60000, NULL, NULL, FALSE); // 1 minute intervals after the DueTime passes

    while (not stopped)
    {
        some task;
        Sleep(900); //sleep for .9 second

        if (WaitForSingleObject(timer, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // has timer elapsed yet?
            method2();
    }

    CancelWaitableTimer(timer);
    CloseHandle(timer);
}
```

Alternatively, waitable timers support APC callbacks, eg:

```
void CallMethod2(LPVOID, DWORD, DWORD)
{
    method2();
}

method1()
{
    HANDLE timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    LARGE_INTEGER DueTime;
    DueTime.QuadPart = -600000000; // due in 1 minute from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer, &DueTime, 60000, &CallMethod2, NULL, FALSE); // 1 minute intervals after the DueTime passes

    while (not stopped)
    {
        some task;
        SleepEx(900, TRUE); //sleep for .9 second, call callback if timer elapsed
    }

    CancelWaitableTimer(timer);
    CloseHandle(timer);
}
```

In either case, you could then expand this to use a second waitable timer to trigger "some task" at .9-second intervals, and then use a `WaitForMultipleObjects()` loop in the 1st case, and a second APC callback in the 2nd case, eg:

```
method1()
{
    HANDLE timer1 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    HANDLE timer2 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER DueTime;

    DueTime.QuadPart = -9000000; // due in 900ms from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer1, &DueTime, 900, NULL, NULL, FALSE); // .9 second intervals after the DueTime passes

    DueTime.QuadPart = -600000000; // due in 1 minute from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer2, &DueTime, 60000, NULL, NULL, FALSE); // 1 minute intervals after the DueTime passes

    HANDLE h[] = {timer1, timer2};

    while (not stopped)
    {
        switch (WaitForMultipleObjects(h, 2, FALSE, INFINITE))
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0+0:
                some task;
                break;
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
                method2();
                break;
        }
    }

    CancelWaitableTimer(timer1);
    CancelWaitableTimer(timer2);
    CloseHandle(timer1);
    CloseHandle(timer2);
}
```

```
void PerformSomeTask(LPVOID, DWORD, DWORD)
{
    some task;
}

void CallMethod2(LPVOID, DWORD, DWORD)
{
    method2();
}

method1()
{
    HANDLE timer1 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    HANDLE timer2 = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER DueTime;

    DueTime.QuadPart = -9000000; // due in 900ms from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer1, &DueTime, 900, &PerformSomeTask, NULL, FALSE); // .9 second intervals after the DueTime passes

    DueTime.QuadPart = -600000000; // due in 1 minute from now
    SetWaitableTimer(timer2, &DueTime, 60000, &CallMethod2, NULL, FALSE); // 1 minute intervals after the DueTime passes

    while (not stopped)
    {
        SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE); //sleep until an APC callback is called
    }

    CancelWaitableTimer(timer1);
    CancelWaitableTimer(timer2);
    CloseHandle(timer1);
    CloseHandle(timer2);
}
```

---

Or, you could use thread-pool timers instead:

```
VOID CALLBACK PerformSomeTask(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE, PVOID, PTP_TIMER)
{
    some task;
}

VOID CALLBACK CallMethod2(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE, PVOID, PTP_TIMER)
{
    method2();
}

method1()
{
    PTP_TIMER timer1 = CreateThreadpoolTimer(&PerformSomeTask, NULL, NULL);
    PTP_TIMER timer2 = CreateThreadpoolTimer(&CallMethod2, NULL, NULL);
    ULARGE_INTEGER DueTime;
    FILETIME ft;

    DueTime.QuadPart = -9000000; // due in 900ms from now
    ft.dwLowDateTime = DueTime.LowPart;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = DueTime.HighPart;
    SetThreadpoolTimer(timer1, &ft, 900, 0); // .9 second intervals after the DueTime passes

    DueTime.QuadPart = -600000000; // due in 1 minute from now
    ft.dwLowDateTime = DueTime.LowPart;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = DueTime.HighPart;
    SetThreadpoolTimer(timer2, &ft, 60000, 0); // 1 minute intervals after the DueTime passes

    wait for stop condition ...

    CloseThreadpoolTimer(timer1);
    CloseThreadpoolTimer(timer2);
}
```

---

Comment: How precise is this. I want method2 be called exactly 1440 times in a day.

Comment: That depends on how often your loop sleeps.  If "some task" takes longer than 1 second, calls to method2 will not be at exact intervals.  If timing is important, consider calling method2 in another thread that is dedicated to that purpose.

Comment: Note how Remy is not using a wall clock. As tempting as it looks to use something simple like `time` to give us time, system time can be changed and that'll really mess up the whole 1440 times a day thing.

Answer (score 0):

> If your loop runs approximately one iteration per second, then anything you do on every 60th iteration of the loop will happen approximately once every minute -- me

> Yes, but how? -- Ramesh

```
int count = 0;
while (1) {
    ...
    if (++count >= 60) {
        count = 0;
        method2();
    }
}
```

---

> precision is very important, method2 should be called exactly 1440 times a day.

That's different. In that case, You should follow Remy Lebeau's advice: Check the actual time of day on every iteration. If it's past the time when method2() should be called, then call it, and re-calculate.

I don't know what the right function calls are for a C++ program. In pseudo code:

```
some_time_type_t method2_due_at = time_now() + 60_seconds;
while (1) {
    ...
    if (time_now() > method2_due_at) {
        method2();
        method2_due_at += 60_seconds;
    }
}
```

Even if the loop doesn't perform exactly 86,400 iterations per day, you'll still get 1440 `method2()` calls per day.

Comment: Also precision is very important, method2 should be called exactly 1440 times a day

Comment: Will try that, Thanks.

Comment: `time_now` would likely be [`std::chrono::steady_clock::now`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now). This will provide a the current time of a nice, predictable monotonic clock. Precision of the clock varies system by system, but seconds should be good enough.